"Why does the phone's keystore never respond?"
After recovering the phone from red state and installing the stock ROM, the keystore simply does not respond anymore after a few minutes of the phone rebooting. As a result, apps stop working like Instagram and the phone's lock screen no longer works, everything related to passwords in fact. The most intriguing thing about all this is that even after formatting the phone and changing the ROM, this problem does not go away, I have even tried to replace all the phone's partitions to the original but still the problem was not solved.
The main technical sign I have of this error are system logcats, here are some of them:
05-17 17:23:31.180   887  1842 W keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(10) IKeystoreSecurityLevel::createOperation Pending: 17530.007071276s Overdue 17529.507128122s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
05-17 17:23:31.180   887  1842 W keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(10) In KeystoreSecurityLevel::create_operation: calling begin Pending: 17530.003237198s Overdue 17529.503244584s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
05-17 17:23:31.180   887  1842 W keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(1) IKeystoreSecurityLevel::createOperation Pending: 17527.360701044s Overdue 17526.860740122s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
05-17 17:23:31.180   887  1842 W keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(1) In KeystoreSecurityLevel::create_operation: calling begin Pending: 17527.358718891s Overdue 17526.858723584s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
05-17 17:23:31.180   887  1842 W keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(5) IKeystoreSecurityLevel::generateKey Pending: 17477.594439426s Overdue 17472.594447041s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
05-17 17:23:31.180   887  1842 W keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(5) In KeystoreSecurityLevel::generate_key (No attestation): calling generate_key. Pending: 17477.59231135s Overdue 17472.592316503s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)

There are also different lines but the entire logcat follows this same structure:
05-09 13:26:24.261   880   880 E beanpodkeymaster: Received 4 byte response
05-09 13:26:24.261   880   880 E beanpodkeymaster: Response of size 4 contained error code -1000
05-09 13:26:24.261   880   880 E beanpodkeymaster: Failed to send cmd 64 err: -1000
05-09 13:26:24.262   879   879 E keystore2: keystore2::error: In generate_key.
05-09 13:26:24.262   879   879 E keystore2:
05-09 13:26:24.262   879   879 E keystore2: Caused by:
05-09 13:26:24.262   879   879 E keystore2:     0: While generating Key without explicit attestation key.
05-09 13:26:24.262   879   879 E keystore2:     1: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-1000))

Anyway, that's all I have for logcats, but there's one more thing I want to add here that I think may be related to this error. The /data/misc/gatekeeper folder is basically empty containing only one file apparently in .bin named '100000'.
Attempt 1: Format the phone. I expected that all the phone files related to my phone's keystore would be factory reset.
Attempt 2: Clear the RPBM partition, I hoped it would remove possible remnants of old ROMs.
Attempt 3: Leave the official phone ROM.
All these attempts failed, just keeping the error.
(Edit: When the phone is restarted, it works normally but only for the first 6 minutes, after this time it returns to this error.)
(edit 2: I restarted the phone in safe mode, and the problem disappeared. Therefore, the issue was likely caused by some app. I will perform tests and return here with a possible solution. Apparently, the keystore was overloaded, as the four most powerful cores of my phone were constantly at 100% usage.)
(edit 3: After conducting some tests, I discovered that this error is being caused by apps like conventional browsers, sound equalization apps like Wavalet, and general banking apps. The issue does not occur with browsers like ADM (which allows torrent usage). Here's a report from Watchdog Keystore:
keystore2::watchdog: ### Keystore Watchdog report - BEGIN ###
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: When extracting from a bug report, please include this header
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: and all 34 records below.
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(105) IKeystoreSecurityLevel::createOperation Pending: 562.93830911s Overdue 562.438317649s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(105) In KeystoreSecurityLevel::create_operation: calling begin Pending: 562.936139957s Overdue 562.436144187s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(24) IKeystoreSecurityLevel::createOperation Pending: 562.302965726s Overdue 561.802973725s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(24) In KeystoreSecurityLevel::create_operation: calling begin Pending: 562.300714034s Overdue 561.800719726s: SecurityLevel SecurityLevel(1)
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(1) IKeystoreService::get_key_entry Pending: 562.17068111s Overdue 561.670701957s
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(1) LegacyImporter::with_try_import Pending: 562.170641572s Overdue 561.670643495s
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(1) KeystoreDB::load_key_entry Pending: 562.170667803s Overdue 561.670669187s
2024-06-02 09:58:15.370   889-9500  keystore2               keystore2                            W  keystore2::watchdog: ThreadId(135) IKeystoreService::get_key_entry Pending: 556.296340341s Overdue 555.80257011
...                           
W  keystore2::watchdog: ### Keystore Watchdog report - END ###

Apparently, these lines are the same as the previous ones, showing only delay reports. This could be interpreted as a momentary system failure, but it doesn’t come with additional details.
So, in this case, I have the hypothesis that this error is caused when attempting to communicate with a server that requires some security measure using the mobile device’s keystore. This hypothesis is based on the following log entry
2024-06-02 10:13:02.237  1619-1831  WifiVendorHal    pid-1619    E  getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.1153) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = }`

Well, this is just a hypothesis since I don’t know exactly what that line means. So, I reiterate that it’s only a hypothesis).

I'm running into a comparable issue. Though for me it takes sometimes more than one day before this happens after a reboot. Rebooting always fixes it temporary. Did you find a solution?
Logcat keeps spamming:
keystore2::error: In create_operation: Failed to begin operation.
Caused by: 0: In upgrade_keyblob_if_required_with: Called closure failed.
1: Error::Rc(ResponseCode(18))
